# Integrating Google Guice support into a custom Java framework

Tags: java, dependency-injection, frameworks, guice

So after a lot of searching and banging my head against a brick wall, I figured it was easier to put this question out there to see if anyone can help.

*To set the backstory to this question:*

I'm currently writing a custom Java framework for a project, which has a small internal DI system that just scans through a class, looks for any fields annotated with @Dependency (provided by the annotations package from my framework) and uses its internal Map to inject instances into those fields.

For reference, this framework is used by client code in the following way:

- Client creates a new Singleton instance of the core manager
- Client builds classes that extend a Base class and implement whatever logic they desire using the framework
- Client registers their class with the manager (essentially: Manager#register(Class<? extends BaseClass)
- The manager will then instantiate the client's class and perform its dependency injection as mentioned above

I'm currently working on building Guice support into this framework so that Clients who are using Guice in their code can get their dependencies from Guice if they so desire. I'd ideally like this to work alongside the framework's internal DI, however this is not a hard requirement. To note, the framework itself *does not* use Guice.

I've currently got two options on my hands from what I can tell:

- Option 1: Get the client to pass their Guice injector into my Guice Handler class and let Guice create the classes via injector.getInstance
- Option 2: Let the client's Guice injector create my Guice Handler class and have a MembersInjector injected into the handler to then call injectMembers on the class instances where required.

Option 1 from what I can tell is a bad approach, for reasons described here: (https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/InjectingTheInjector)

So I'm currently working towards Option 2. This would require the client code to do something like:

`Manager manager = new Manager();`

`Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new ClientModule();`

`manager.enableGuiceSupport(injector.getInstance(GuiceHandler.class)` Or:

`GuiceHandler guiceHandler = new GuiceHandler();`

`injector.injectMembers(guiceHandler);`

`manager.enableGuiceSupport(guiceHandler);`

Obviously Guice needs to deal with the GuiceHandler class so that I can get the MembersInjector injected.

Looking at this, whilst a valid solution to the problem, its adding a requirement on the client that feels slightly labored. The aim of the framework is to reduce what the client code needs to do, not add to it.

So my question boils down to this:

- Is my approach to Option 2 here a good way to move forward and I just accept that the client needs to "bootstrap" the GuiceHandler?
- Or alternatively, is there just a better way to achieve the goal of adding Guice support?

Any thoughts, suggestions and constructive criticism is welcome!

(To everyone who's taken the time to read through all this to see if you can help, have a cookie: . I really appreciate your time!)

Comment: My 2c is that you should write a library which is DI agnostic. Then if you want to write a simple DI framework too, do so, but don't let your library have any dependencies on it. Then clients can use your library with whatever DI they like. The last thing a user wants is to have to understand the details of how your bespoke DI interacts with the DI they know well.

Comment: @tgdavies Thank you for your feedback! Most of the stuff I write usually is implementation-agnostic as far as possible. I feel going down the completely DI agnostic route here might be a little out of scope at the moment, but I definitely might look at refactoring this slightly to extract the DI stuff into its own modules (one for internal and one for optional Guice support).
Its worth mentioning that in many of the use cases, I am the client of my own library here (which makes it ironic for me worrying about one extra line of code!).
Thank you again, I'll definitely consider restructuring!

Comment: You should probably re-visit option 1.  Although the document says to "do it as little as possible", if you're only doing it once then you're using it as intended.  This follows how web frameworks like RESTEasy work with guice.  In your example you could do `manager.enableInjection(new GuiceManager(injector))` where `enableInjection` would take an interface for any DI (as mentioned by @tgdavies).

Comment: @kendavidson Thanks! I've implemented something which resembles a hybrid between opt. 1 & 2. I have an implementation-agnostic interface which requires an implementation to return an instance when given its class, and may optionally provide an implementation to inject for an already instantiated instance.
The core manager allows registering an arbitrary number of injectors. When an instance is requested, it iterates through the injectors to instantiate the class. Then it tries the remaining injectors for post-instantiation injection (default returns the original instance). Seems to work OK :)